# Terraform: Error while passing autoscaling group name in aws_autoscaling_schedule resource

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting an error while parsing module output to another module resource.

Error:

```
* module.scheduled_action.aws_autoscaling_schedule.asg[0]: 1 error(s) occurred:

    * aws_autoscaling_schedule.asg.0: Error Creating Autoscaling Scheduled Action: ValidationError: AutoScalingGroup name not found - null
        status code: 400, request id: eedacea2-4819-11e9-a48e-2178a7946e4b
    * module.scheduled_action.aws_autoscaling_schedule.asg[1]: 1 error(s) occurred:

    * aws_autoscaling_schedule.asg.1: Error Creating Autoscaling Scheduled Action: ValidationError: AutoScalingGroup name not found - null
        status code: 400, request id: eedbb8f2-4819-11e9-a103-ed59f82b87f3
```

Code:

scheduled.tf

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "asg" {
  count = "${var.actions_count}"
  ..
  ...
  ....
  autoscaling_group_name = "{var.autoscaling_group_name}"
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "autoscaling_group_name" {}
```

main.tf

```
autoscaling_group_name = "${module.launch_configs.asg_name}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You mix the module variables with local variable.

In `main.tf`, the value of `autoscaling_group_name` is coming from a module called `launch_configs`, so you can use the same name in resource `aws_autoscaling_schedule`

The code can be changed to

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "asg" {
  count = "${var.actions_count}"
  ..
  ...
  ....
  autoscaling_group_name = "${module.launch_configs.asg_name}"
}
```

In your case, the definition of variable `autoscaling_group_name` in `variables.tf` is useless. You can delete it.